# How can this function be surjective when there is a finite set mapped to an infinite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity, finite-element-method

Question:

Consider the set $W$ of words over the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$, i.e., the set of all ﬁnite non-empty sequences of letters chosen among $a, b$ and $c$ – for example, $aa, babb$ and $bbc$ are all elements of $W$.

Let $\rm{counta}$  be the function from $W$ to $\mathbb{N}$(Natural Numbers) that counts the number of times the letter $a$ occurs, i.e., given $w \in W$, $\rm{counta}(w)$ is the number of times $a$ occurs in $w$.

I was told that $\rm{counta}$ is surjective but I don't understand why.
Surjection $y = f(x)$, but the set $W$ is finite so how can you map all of $W$ to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: W is not finite, it's just generated by a finite set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $W$ is not finite. The *alphabet* is finite, but we can create arbitrarily long words out of this alphabet, and hence $W$ will be infinite (if you have heard of such things, $W$ is in fact *countably infinite*). For instance, consider the subset 
$$
\{a,aa,aaa,\dots\}\subset W.
$$
Does this help you see surjectivity?

Comment: Thanks for catching that; I was thinking of infinite sequences, not finite words

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this!